# How can I make custom function and response in Yii2?

Tags: api, rest, yii2

Currently I am playing with REST API on Yii2 framework. I have already established basic functions and unset some of theme.

```
public function actions()
{
    // GET ACTIONS
    $actions = parent::actions();
    // UNSET ACTIONS
    unset($actions['delete'], $actions['create']);
    // CUSTOM FUNCTION FOR INDEX
    $actions['index']['prepareDataProvider'] = [$this, 'actionIndex'];

    return $actions;
}
```

and I added custom function which is currently just a copy of original.

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    /* @var $modelClass \yii\db\BaseActiveRecord */
    $modelClass = $this->modelClass;
    return new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $modelClass::find(),
    ]);
}
```

This calls DB table products. Now I want to get product ID 1 on `localhost/api/v1/products/1`
and return is:

```
<response>
        <id>1</id>
        <product>Product 1</product>
</response>
```

I also have relation table of products and I would like my API to return

```
<response>
        <id>1</id>
        <product>Product 1</product>
        <related>
            <id>2</id>
            <id>5</id>
        </related>
</response>
```

I have no idea how to modify the whole function not just data provider preparation. I need to do 2 SQL queries - first one to get product data and the second one to get related product and merge theme in response.

Thank you for your answer in advanced.

Comment: You should not modify the function for this, there is another function that returns the details about 1 item. Read the Rest API docs again.

Comment: What are other function to return details? Regarding [YII2 Doc Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html) there are only GET and HEAD methods to get detailed data... However that was not my question at all. I want to modify the function that returns data and looking for solution. No matter what the return modification is... It can be `status:0, data: [data]`

Answer (score 0):

You can add `fields()` and `extraFields()` methods in your model to achieve this as per explained here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-resources.html#fields

So in your case you can use:

```
public function extraFields() {
  return ['__relation_name_here__'];
}
```

Comment: You may also name the field returned, in this case like:  `return ['related' => '__relation_name_here']`